# Python Tkinter numpad buttons and multiple inputs

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically I'm trying to make it so that when you change `Entry` input fields the button will append it's label to the correct input.

I'm using `active_entry` to target the input that was just focused in. For some reason the event binding isn't properly changing it to the new input field.

Actual result after changing from the default `Entry` then pressing `button_1`: `TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string`

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.set_active_entry('entry_1_var')  # set initial active entry
        self.entry_1_var = StringVar()
        self.entry_2_var = StringVar()
        self.entry_1 = Entry(self, width=10, font='Helvetica 32', textvariable=self.entry_1_var)
        self.entry_2 = Entry(self, width=10, font='Helvetica 32', textvariable=self.entry_2_var)
        self.create_widgets()
        self.entry_binding()

    def set_active_entry(self, name):
        self._active_entry = name
        print(self._active_entry)

    @property
    def active_entry(self):
        return getattr(self, self._active_entry)

    @active_entry.setter
    def active_entry(self, value):
        setattr(self, self._active_entry, value)

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.entry_1.pack()
        self.entry_2.pack()

        label = '1'
        button_1 = Button(self, text=label, width=10, height=5, command=lambda x=label: self.num_pad(x))
        button_1.pack()

    def entry_binding(self):
        self.entry_1.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda x='entry_1_var': self.set_active_entry(x))
        self.entry_2.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda x='entry_2_var': self.set_active_entry(x))

    def num_pad(self, label):
        current_text = self.active_entry.get()
        self.active_entry.set(current_text+label)

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in these lines

```
self.entry_1.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda x='entry_1_var': self.set_active_entry(x))
self.entry_2.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda x='entry_2_var': self.set_active_entry(x))
```

When you click one of the entries you see `<FocusIn event>` being printed, when instead you would have expected it to be either `entry_1_var` or `entry_2_var` right?

What happens is that the `bind` function automatically passes an event object to the function you specify. In your lambda function, the first argument is `x`. You did specify a default value, but since an actual object is passed by the `bind` function, x is the event object. So in `def set_active_entry(self, name):`, `name` is not the name of your widget but rather the event object. Therefore, when you call `getattr(self, self._active_entry)`, `self._active_entry` is the event object and you get an error.

The fix for this is actually pretty easy, just accept an argument in your lambda function to accept the event object and make sure you actually pass the string with the name to the `set_active_entry` function:

```
self.entry_1.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda e, x='entry_1_var': self.set_active_entry(x))
self.entry_2.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda e, x='entry_2_var': self.set_active_entry(x))
```

or

```
self.entry_1.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda e: self.set_active_entry('entry_1_var'))
self.entry_2.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda e: self.set_active_entry('entry_2_var'))
```